# Whats the important specifications for a GPU

Tags: gpu, hashrate, hardware

Which specifications are important for a GPU to get a high Hashrate.

- Frequency
- GPU Clock Speed
- Graphics Ram Type
- Memory Bus Width
- Memory Speed?

or another important thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I just want to verify with you, the 290X has 2816 stream processors and a 512 bit memory bus.

I'm quite new to this mining but found some information you may find quite useful. It's from another thread about GPU specs affecting mining performance:
https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/3924/gpu-key-specs-for-high-hasrate

It all seems to depend on which hashing algorithm we're talking about. I basically got that memory *bandwidth* has a huge affect on the hashrate of the GPU, and that in some cases you can even under-clock the core clock to achieve higher efficiency while mining. One guy in the thread made a spread sheet with some benchmarks he ran on several cards which claims that GCN 1.0 cards performed the best with modern cards falling short. So Radeon HD 78XX , HD 79XX, R9 2XX cards do quite well.

As for how the specs affect the hashrate? Really all I've found is higher memory bandwidth is key. **Also,** before you go buy like 4 Fury X's with HBM memory, keep in mind that memory is clocked much lower than GDDR5 memory, so the *effective* memory bandwidth is not as crazy high as one might hope for. I've got a MSI Lightning R9 290X and am considering getting into ether mining so I'm curious as to what others here have to say. Check out the link I pasted, as it's pretty much got this exact discussion going.

Answer (score 0):

The number of processors on the board:

Example a AMD R9-290x has 8192 Stream Processors on the board.

Comment: are you sure that the AMD R9-290x has 8192 Stream Processors? See https://hothardware.com/reviews/amd-radeon-r9-290x-review-welcome-to-hawaii they have only 2816 Stream Processors?

Answer (score -4):

Ok so I'm still trying to figure out what makes one card outperform another and its mind boggling I know this thread is super old but whatever ok so the 290x only get about 25 mh/s on eth it's got 2816 steeam processors now I know more about nvidia but that should be about equivalent to coda cores on nvidia as I know these are somewhat important  the new 3080 has 8704 of these and gets up to100 mh/s most rate it closer to 85 the 3070 has 5888 and is rated about 56 the 3060ti has 4864 and some how get about 50 that where this starts making a little less sense but someone said you were incorrect and it's only 2816 then it would make sense cause the 3090 only get like 120 hash at most not that much over 3080 has 10496 cuda cores but 24 gb gddr6 and only boosted up to 384 bit interface width now the 3080 has 10gb ddr6 while the other 2 only have 8 does the 2gb really make that difference or is the the 320 bit memory interface width vs the other 2 having only 256 bit but yet the 290x has 512 bit and mines so much less I wont have a more clear conclusion till I get the hash rate of the new 3060 standard cause it has 12 gb so more gddr6 but only 192bit and only 3584 cuda cores if vram is one of the more important factor the new 3060 is gonna be the ultimate buy for mining but we shall see I kinda doubt it I think all factors go into play but amount of cores seems to be the most important factor so far making out of new cards the 3080 the best buy for the coat if you can get your hands on it for the 700 it's supposed to be cause the 1500 for the 3090 doesnt do enough extra other than for actual gaming and you would have to be playing some of the most intense games when it comes to need for graphics cause the 3080 does more than enough for most games

Comment: Just realized I said the corrected number the first time

Comment: Downvoting the answer, because it is unreadable (the author does not use English sentence structure and finish sentences with period)